# Aggressive find and replace on Trademark Guidance

Tags: bug, status-completed, legal, stackexchange.com

With the recent name change to Stack Exchange, Inc., the [Trademark Guidance](https://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance) has been accidentally impacted:

> But **Stack Exchange** and **Stack Exchange** are the name of our company and services, so we have to be cautious about any confusion that may cause.

Twice mentioned is twice as important.

> The API is always referred to as **"Stack Exchange API"**, even if the application is written for a specific site (i.e. never **Stack Exchange API**, Server Fault API, etc.).

So what should I call it?

Comment: Nice catch ;) That's the problem with find and replace.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good catch. Lazy/hasty find-and-replace. It's fixed now.